# adding online API, android

Tags: android, api

https://codingsquared-prod.apigee.net/masaajid?lat=40.518715&long=-74.41209500000002

this is a online API which i want to add in my app
i want to add the latitude and longitude to my map, but for now i cant figure out how to read the API and what to do with it
i would also like to put each different id in a listview as well
any help in how to read this API would be great, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should learn how to work with JSON. Here is a good [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/) I found about it.